# unity - importing textures to fbx file

Tags: unity-game-engine, textures, fbx

I am using Unity 2018.3.44f1. I download a backgammon 3d model. I got a folder of textures and max file. I converted from max file to fbx. But, unfortunately I couldn't be able to understand how to import the textures into the fbx model. It shows me the model without any color/material expect of black.

[image: Tried the option Extract Textures while clicking on the model but It was disable for me .]

[image: Folders in my project]

Answer (score 0):

The solution is very simple

Step 1: Press "Extract Materials", it will save materials in your Asset folder.

Step 2: Select each materials, and assign your Textures manually

Step 3: Check the color, reflection..settings, it could be just black from your default source fbx.

Comment: The problem is that I didn't build this object and therefore I don't know which textures to put in each part..